# Return to the previous page after executing response.write in VB scripting

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to execute the following VB script where i have two reponse.redirect statement. My code works for the first response and then stays on that particular page. How can i execute the second response.redirect statement.
Here is my code -

```
<%

'Code to insert details into database

'At the end

Response.Redirect "/school/Subject/Course/Course.asp?courseCode=" &Course
Response.Redirect "/School/Subject/Calendar/Enroll.asp?id=" &id

%>
```

Please suggest me any way to execute both the lines. I tried windows.back() in the course.asp but it did not work.

Comment: open both in _blank, that way you can pass both values, however it'll open in a new window.... Unless you edit Course.asp, and pass query parameters for BOTH &Course, and &id. Then upon load pass &id to Enroll.asp. It'll take some redesign.

Comment: Sounds like you don't understand the basics of how HTTP works, otherwise you wouldn't be trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not open two pages at same time.

This can be  done using  one by one like below

Pass querystring as IsEnroll=True

```
Response.Redirect "/school/Subject/Course/Course.asp?IsEnroll=True&courseCode=" &Course
```

In Course.asp Page

```
If Request.QueryString["IsEnroll"] !=null
{

Response.Redirect "/School/Subject/Calendar/Enroll.asp?id=" &id

}
```

Comment: The OP is using VBScript, so why post JScript code? This will just confuse the situation more than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested, but perhaps you can use (2) window.open scripts if you don't mind 2 additional browser window(s) being open. It'll pass your parameters through, and it'll leave you with 3 windows total, but it gets the job done.

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('/school/Subject/Course/Course.asp?courseCode=" + Course + "','_blank');</script>");
Response.Write("<script>window.open('/School/Subject/Calendar/Enroll.asp?id=" + id + "','_blank');</script>");
```

Unless you edit Course.asp, and pass in querystring parameters for BOTH &Course, and &id. Then upon load pass &id from Course.asp to Enroll.asp. It'd take some significant redesign, and you'd need access to the source code.

Haven't seen much Classic ASP these days, sounds/looks like a Legacy System.